# Laravel + Guzzle load test performance issue

Tags: php, laravel, curl, laravel-5, guzzle

I have a web app that uses Laravel 5.2 with Guzzle 6.0 that connects to Laravel API. I notice that when I open multiple pages at the same time on the web app, I usually get an error of:

`cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: <table name> (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)`

Wherein `<table name>` is the name of the database table. Checking into the log file it produces, it is getting a time out exception.

`local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded' in C:\localhost\...\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php:503
Stack trace:...`

Note that this only occurs when I open several pages opened simultaneously as well as having several users accessing the site.

No problem occuring when user opens a page one by one. Just happens when opened at the same time or just spam-refresh.

```
public function connect($apiUrl, $args, $response)
{
    try {
        $params = ['auth'  => [env('USERNAME'), env('PASSWORD')]];

        if ($response == 'get') {
            $params['query'] = $args;
        } else {
            $params['form_params'] = $args;
        }

        $apiResponse = $this->_restClient->request($response, env('URL') . env('PREFIX') . $apiUrl, $params)->getBody();

        return ($apiResponse == true) ? true : json_decode($apiResponse, true);
    } catch (RequestException $e) {
        if ($e->hasResponse()) throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the server load, cpu utilization, memory consumption, etc?  What is the full request that is being made? Is it different then the ones that succeed?  Also, why does the error message list a db table name instead of the host portion of your Uri? Also, the server that this code snippet is running on, is DNS resolving working properly on it?

Comment: According to my hosting provider, the reason why it became slow it that it consumes 40+ processes. I have no problem when I deployed it to my staging where 2-5 users access it simultaneously. It just happened when I deployed it to production where 1000++ users access it simultaneously. Is there an open-source application that could stress test and do load balance test? I think the application couldn't handle multiple users accessing the site simultaneously.

Comment: a lot of people will use the apache bench tool to stress test applications.